# creating arrays on-demand in java

Tags: java, arrays, theory, self-modifying

I consider myself an intermediate Java programmer having been at it for a year and a half and having some experience in other languages. However I have run into an issue that I feel I need an experts help on.

As I understand it arrays when created by java exist somewhat outside of where they were created i.e. if you create an array called s in one class and another called s in a second class then try to use both those classes as part of a program you will run into problems with them overwriting each other.

However this brings me to an interesting dilemma. What if one wanted to create a unique array on-demand for an infinite number of sets of user input. i.e. is it possible to have the user enter a string value for use as the array name or have a generic value that then gets a number or letter appended to it. This is more a theoretical issue (there being other ways to accomplish the same thing) but any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Every time you create an array with `new`, you get a new array. Doing something like `fooArray = barArray` doesn't create a new array, it only copies the reference contained in `barArray` to `fooArray`. That reference is basically an address, but copying that address means both references point to the same object. It's like how writing your address down on a card doesn't copy your house; just means there's a new way of finding your address.

Comment: Objects created on a class will not be usable in another class only because they have the same name. Can you provide an example of what you're saying ? I think you misunderstood something, but I cannot say what at the moment.

Comment: It may help if you posted a simple, self-contained snippet of code that illustrates the case you're talking about. Otherwise we can only guess as to what specifically is tripping you up.

Comment: @yshavit +1 for the metaphor, I like it, handy one.

Answer (score 1):

> i.e. is it possible to have the user enter a string value for use as
>   the array name or have a generic value that then gets a number or
>   letter appended to it.

The user should not need to care about your array names. The name of an array should neither be visible to the user, nor should it affect your application in any way.

If you want to allow the user to create *collections of elements* that he can store under a *FriendlyName* you could use a (Hash)map for that:

```
Map<String, Integer[]> userDefinedArrays = new HashMap<>();

userDefinedArrays.put("NameTheUserSelectsForThisArray", new Integer[]{1,2,3});
```

The "Key" of this map will be the *FriendlyName* provided by the user - he still does not know, that the actual map is called `userDefinedArrays` - or even `someMapThatHoldsSomeThingsTheUserWantToUse.`

The name of a actual *variable* needs to be set during designtime and is fixed (at least in java)

> if you create an array called s in one class and another called s in a second class then try to use both those classes as part of a program you will run into problems with them overwriting each other.

No! Each Variable declared exists inside it's own scope! You can change the value of an array inside it's scope, and also reuse the same name inside different scopes - it doesn't matter. If you try to redeclare a variable already existing *withing the current scope* your compiler will warn you! - you simple can not do that.

Example:

```
class MyApplication{
   public static void Main(String[] args){
      Integer[] arr1;
      Integer[] arr1; //Compiler error!
   }
}
```

but:

```
class MyApplication{
   public static void Main(String[] args){
      Integer[] arr1;
      Integer[] arr2; 
   }
}
```

or

```
class MyApplication{
   public static void Main(String[] args){
      foo();
      bar();
   }

   public static void foo(){
      Integer[] arr1;
   }  

   public static void bar(){
      Integer[] arr1;
   }  
}
```

is fine. `arr1` just exists within the scope of either `foo()` or `bar()`.

Answer (score 0):

Two different class you're talking about is **ClassOne** & **ClassTwo** in my example. As you told, there is some kind of conflict while keeping the field name same. I've used **arr** for both classes. The reason to make **MyArray** super class is just code reuse. Why I used abstract MyArray class & why I used public static field isn't our matter of discussion. In **TestApp**, I've used **arr** of both classes **ClassOne** & **ClassTwo** without any problem.
`is it possible to have the user enter a string value for use as the array name`
IMHO it may be possible using Reflection API or Dynamically Typed Language can do it. I'm not much sure about that.

```
class ClassOne extends MyArray {
    public static int[] arr = new int[5];
}

class ClassTwo extends MyArray {
    public static int[] arr = new int[5];
}

abstract class MyArray {
    public static void setValue(int arr[], int index, int value) {
        arr[index] = value;
    }

    public static void printArray(int[] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}


public class TestApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ClassOne.setValue(ClassOne.arr, 1, 30);
        ClassTwo.setValue(ClassTwo.arr, 1, 50);

        ClassOne.printArray(ClassOne.arr);
        ClassOne.printArray(ClassTwo.arr);
        ClassTwo.printArray(ClassOne.arr);
        ClassTwo.printArray(ClassTwo.arr);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand it arrays when created by java exist somewhat outside of where they were created i.e. if you create an array called s in one class and another called s in a second class then try to use both those classes as part of a program you will run into problems with them overwriting each other.

I think maybe you are misunderstanding. This will not happen unless you do it intentionally like yshavit points out in your comments. A member of a class named S in the class Cat, will not point to a member named S in the Dog class. You would have to go out of your way to do this.

**In short, this will not happen by accident most of the time if you are instantiating your classes without passing references between them when you do.**

> What if one wanted to create a unique array on-demand for an infinite number of sets of user input.

You may want to use an ArrayList

```
ArrayList<String[]> myList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

Or a hashmap

```
Map<Integer,String[]> myMap = new HashMap<Integer,String[]>();
```

**Which one you use depends on what you are using it for.** If you need faster access to arbitrary elements use a map. If you plan to access them iteratively, an ArrayList will work fine.

> is it possible to have the user enter a string value for use as the array name or have a generic value that then gets a number or letter appended to it. This is more a theoretical issue (there being other ways to accomplish the same thing) but any insight would be greatly appreciated.

In this case you want to use the hashmap solution, You can choose the key type of a map in java quite easily.

You will want to read this

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

or this, to get started.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html